# Sinon: testing that a setter throws an exception not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, sinon

I am trying to test that an Angular component's setter will throw an error using Sinon. My component looks partially like this:

```
@Input( 'sceneMode' ) set sceneMode( newSceneMode: Cesium.SceneMode ) {
    const scene = this.cesiumViewerService.getScene();

    switch ( newSceneMode ) {
        case Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D:
            scene.morphTo2D( MORPH_DURATION );
            break;

        case Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D:
            scene.morphTo3D( MORPH_DURATION );
            break;

        case Cesium.SceneMode.COLUMBUS_VIEW:
            scene.morphToColumbusView( MORPH_DURATION );
            break;

        default:
            throw new Error( `Cannot morph to SceneMode type ${newSceneMode}` );
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
it( 'should throw an error on invalid scene mode', () => {
    sceneModeStub = sinon.stub( component, 'sceneMode' );
    try {
        sceneModeStub.sceneMode = 0;
    } finally {
        assert( sceneModeStub.threw() );
    }
} );
```

I have tried moving the assert outside of the finally block. I have also tried using:

```
sceneModeStub = sinon.sandbox.stub( component, 'sceneMode' );
```

but Karma reports:

> AssertionError: false == true

I know for certain that `0` is an invalid `sceneMode` and in fact if I remove the try/finally, the application throws the error in the component's setter.

How do I test this?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but to answer in case it's still relevant.

It looks to me like you're stubbing the method that you want to test, which would be wrong. The method you want to test should always stay in original form, only dependencies should be stubbed.

When testing an exception one should pass in a function to sinon which it can call in order to cause the exception. This should work:

```
it( 'should throw an error on invalid scene mode', () => {
    assert.threw( () => {
        sceneModeStub.sceneMode = 0;
    }, 'Cannot morph to SceneMode type 0')
} );
```